# Mean color for each superpixel in an image in the CIELAB color space

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

According to the MATLAB's help for measuring mean color for each superpixel, I segment an image to 200 superpixels and I tried to set the color of each pixel in the output image to the mean CIELAB color of the superpixel region.
The input image is shown below:

[image: The input image]

```
B=imread('H.jpg');
A=rgb2lab(B);    // conversion from rgb to lab
```

[image: output of command of imshow(A,[])]

```
[L,N] = superpixels(A,200);
figure
BW = boundarymask(L);
imshow(imoverlay(A,BW,'cyan'),'InitialMagnification',67);


outputImage = zeros(size(A),'like',A);
idx = label2idx(L);
numRows = size(A,1);
numCols = size(A,2);
for labelVal = 1:N
  redIdx = idx{labelVal};
  greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+numRows*numCols;
  blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*numRows*numCols;
  outputImage(redIdx) = mean(A(redIdx));
  outputImage(greenIdx) = mean(A(greenIdx));
  outputImage(blueIdx) = mean(A(blueIdx));
end    
figure
imshow(outputImage,'InitialMagnification',67);
```

[image: segmented image in the CIELAB color space]

[image: mean color of each superpixel in the CIELAB color space]

I am not sure that output of this code gives me the correct mean color of each superpixel in the CIELAB color space correctly. Does the image have such a different color compared to the RGB color space or is the code incorrect? In the measurement of mean color of channels of CIELAB color space, is there any problem in the code?

Comment: I code in MATLAB 2018.

Comment: I use from MATLAB help.RGB has 3 channels and determining the mean color is done within each channel. but because of properties of CIELAB color space, I don't know how to measure the mean color for each superpixels after conversion of image from RGB TO CIELAB color space?

Comment: It maybe work for you : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/285112-conversion-of-rgb-images-into-lab-color-space

Comment: The images is in blue links.

Comment: @CrisLuengo,Please let me know about your comment about the code and images. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that what `imshow` shows you is not what the data contains.

`imshow` assumes, for `double` inputs, that the pixel values are in the range [0,1]. Lab has a range of [0,100] in the first channel, and I believe it is [-20,20] in the other two channels (maybe it’s different, but these two channels are symmetric around 0, which is gray).

If you do `imshow(A,[])` then the data will be scaled to show you everything. Thus will scale all the channels the same, so it’s not the best way to look at your data either, but in any case the L channel will be shown in red, and the a and b channels in green and blue. Don’t expect this to look like your original image at all, even though you still have all the data to recover your original image.

<strike>Next, `superpixels` expects an RGB image as input, consider passing the original image `B`, rather than the Lab image `A`. This will not preclude you from computing means of the Lab channels within superpixels found.</strike> ([it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965431/7328782) there is an option to use an Lab input image).

If you want to measure the mean Lab values within each superpixel and use that in further processing, don't create the `outputImage`, but rather a table with these values:

```
data = zeros(N,3);
for labelVal = 1:N
  redIdx = idx{labelVal};
  greenIdx = idx{labelVal}+numRows*numCols;
  blueIdx = idx{labelVal}+2*numRows*numCols;
  data(labelVal,1) = mean(A(redIdx));
  data(labelVal,2) = mean(A(greenIdx));
  data(labelVal,3) = mean(A(blueIdx));
end
```

Now, `data(ii,:)` is the Lab values for superpixel number `ii`. `L==ii` are the pixels that belong to this superpixel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I compute superpixels using the RGB image, in which step conversion to LAB should be done? By considering range of each LAB channels that you mentioned above, the measuremnt of mean color of LAB channels has been done correctrly in the code?

Comment: @dtr43: compute superpixels from the RGB image `B`, then when computing the averages use the Lab image `A`. The conversion would be done anytime before you need `A`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after measuring the mean color in CIELAB color space, I have the 'outputImage' image that color of the superpixels' regions are the mean LAB color. How could access to the these superpixels in the new image that each pixels have the mean LAB color?

Comment: @dtr43: you can convert the image to RGB for display.

Comment: In other words, I mean for some operations between superpixels, we need to access to each super pixel individually which has mean color in cielab color space. But the 'outputimage' don't give us this accessibility. Operations like Euclidean distance, ... . how can access to them in this situation?

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect and works. in the `data` which one of channels is _L_ and which one is _a_ and which one is _b_ in CIELAB color space? What is your mean about `L==ii` and pixels?

Comment: "Lab" indicates the order of the channels. L is the first channel, a the second, b the third. Try `imshow(L==ii)` (for any given number `ii` between 1 and `N`), you'll see a binary image with the pixels for superpixel `ii` selected.

Answer (score 3):

Note that though the superpixels algorithm, SLIC, operates in L*a*b* space, it expects an RGB image as input. If you want the pre-compute the L*a*b* representation for downstream use like in your use case, you need to use the 'IsInputLab' Name/Value. Otherwise, the algorithm is going to attempt to convert an already L*a*b* image to L*a*b*.

You want:

```
B=imread('H.jpg');
A=rgb2lab(B);  
[L,N] = superpixels(A, 200,'IsInputLab',true);
```

Chris Lueno has aleady answered the mean computation of features in the superpixel graph. Distance between superpixels is similar, where you essentially compute centroid features for each superpixel to describe their position and then measure the distance between them. Note that in the code below, the matrix is symmetric about its diagonal and 0 on the diagonal. I'll leave it to you to make this more efficient if you care about that.

```
distanceMatrix = zeros(N,N);
for m = 1:N
    for n = 1:n
        [i1,j1] = ind2sub(size(A),idx{m});
        [i1,j2] = ind2sub(size(A),idx{n});
        Icenter1 = mean(i1);
        Jcenter1 = mean(j1);
        Icenter2 = mean(i2);
        Jcenter2 = mean(j2);
        distanceMatrix(m,n) = sqrt((Icenter1-Icenter2)^2+(Jcenter1-Jcenter2)^2);
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in other words, I could measure the mean value of each superpixel in CIELAB color space and the output image is uploaded in this link:  https://uploadfiles.io/jl4oy                                                                                                 My question is How can I access to this value of mean values in  each superpixels individually to do some operations such as euclidean distance, ... between superpixels ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your new answer. I really need that.